# closing the streams of I/o

Tags: java, stream, io

What are the bad things that can happen when I don't close the stream?

Does the close operation automatically flush?

Are all the streams closed after the program exits?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this post, it has the similar question with some good answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/515975/closing-streams-in-java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bad things that can happen when you don't close your streams:

- you can run out of file handles
- data that you think is written to disk may still be in the buffer (only)
- files might still be locked for other processes (depends on the platform)
- ...

Yes, close operation always flushes the stream.

All file handles that the OS is aware of are closed. This means effectively that `FileOutputStream`, `FileInputStream` and the input/output of a `Socket` will be closed. But if you wrap a `FileOutputStream` in a `BufferedOutputStream` then that `BufferedOutputStream` will *not* be known to the OS and *won't* be closed/flushed on shutdown. So data written to the `BufferedOutputStream` but not yet flushed to the `FileOutputStream` can be lost.

Comment: SO ALL streams are closed automatically when the program exits..close operation flushes automatically ..so i am safe isn't it

Comment: Actually: I've not been entirely correct. I edited my answer.

Comment: why FileInputStream and OutputStream are only known to os ..why not BufferedOutputStream

Comment: @saravanan: `File*Stream` represent direct OS resources (namely open file handles). A `BufferedOutputStream` is a pure Java object that wraps another output-stream. There's no need for the OS to know of its existance.

Comment: What happens if the stream goes out of scope? May all resources be recollected, including the file handles, by the GC?

Answer (score 3):

1) You tie up system resources unnecessarily (e.g. file descriptors). Possibly to the extent of running out of them.

2) Yes (although you should check the documentation of the particular stream you're interested in to be sure).

3) Yes

Comment: In the project I'm working previous person, was not closing file descriptors, after few days of running there were thousands of exceptions :D

Answer (score 1):

To qualify, when you perform a close(), it flushes the data and closes the file handle.  If you exit, the file handle is closed but un-flushed data is lost.