# Should I close a JarFile if it throws an I/O error when opening it? (Do the general rules for handling streams apply?)

Tags: java, stream, inputstream, ioexception, fclose

`new JarFile(path)` can trow an I/O exception.

If that happens, and I catch the exception, should I close it? (I guess the real question is, is there anything to close?)

The other question is: if it works, should I clean up? I.e., do the [general rules for dealing with streams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5155122/2018047) apply?

Sorry if the question is a bit naff; I'm new to dealing with `JarFile` (and haven't really used streams in the past, either).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to close if `new JarFile(path)` throws an `IOException`:

```
JarFile file = null;

try {
    file = new JarFile("does/not/exist");
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(file); //Prints out null
}

try {
    file.close(); //Throws NullPointerException
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```