# How concerned should I be about the loss blocked in valgrind

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

In my code I have a class `lipid` which holds three `bead`s:

```
struct lipid{
  particle mainPart;
  bead * head;
  bead * body;
  bead * tail;
  int LID;
  vec direction;
  bead * operator[](int index){
    switch(index){
    case 0: return head;
    case 1: return body;
    case 2: return tail;
    default: return body;
    }
  }
};


struct bead{
  particle mainPart;
  int charge;
  int type;
  double rho;
  double nextRho;
  int LID;
  double U;
  double nextU;
  bool touch;
};


struct particle{
  vec pos;
  vec oldPos;
  vec vel;
  vec oldVel;
  vec F;
  vec oldF;
 };

class vec{
  velarry<double> coor;
  double x;
  double y;
  double z;
}
```

When I try to create a lipid, I create three beads using new

```
lipid * l = new lipid;
l->head = new bead;
l->body = new bead;
l->tail = new bead;
```

When I valgrind my code, I get an error which claims that there is loads of block missing... How concerned should I be about that? I should state that I'm pushing the `bead`s and the `lipid`s into (several) vectors.

**Edit**
Ok, adding `delete head` .. fixed that but I still have an aching problem, I have a line:

```
this->beadBoxes[t[0]][t[1]][t[2]].push_back(b);
```

Where `t` is a `vector<int>` of size 3 and `beadsBoxes` is:

```
<vector<vector<vector<vector<bead*> > > > beadBoxes;
```

This guy gives me 5 times a memory leak error:

```
==22458== 48 bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 11 of 106
==22458==    at 0x4A0666E: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:220)
==22458==    by 0x419A3C: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<bead*>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:88)
==22458==    by 0x419A64: std::_Vector_base<bead*, std::allocator<bead*> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:127)
==22458==    by 0x423E1F: std::vector<bead*, std::allocator<bead*> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<bead**, std:\
:vector<bead*, std::allocator<bead*> > >, bead* const&) (vector.tcc:275)
==22458==    by 0x424073: std::vector<bead*, std::allocator<bead*> >::push_back(bead* const&) (stl_vector.h:610)
==22458==    by 0x409664: membrane::updateBox(bead*) (membrane.cpp:874)
==22458==    by 0x40ACA5: membrane::decide(lipid*) (membrane.cpp:793)
==22458==    by 0x40DF01: membrane::rotate() (membrane.cpp:529)
==22458==    by 0x40DFAF: membrane::MCstep() (membrane.cpp:480)
==22458==    by 0x401B54: main (main.cpp:15)
```

Which I suspect might be related to a segmentation fault which happens is that line. Why does the new (unsigned long) occur and why might it throw a segmentation fault?

Comment: Um - are you deleting the beads + lipid? Obviously if you don't delete them you will get a leak...

Comment: No, they are kept until the end of the run. When I only create the lipid (without the beads) there is no such message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the other posters excellently explained, these lost blocks are memory that was allocated, but never freed, and thus will never be usable again in the same run of your program.

When you try to run your program for a longer time and need many new lipid structures, this is a definitive problem. From a software engineering POV, you must deallocate your memory. However, you seem to program in a scientific context, and thus I'd like to add that your results are not influenced by the missing deallocation and, from the scientists' POV, you might be able to afford being sloppy here.

Answer (score 3):

Did you free the objects allocated with `new`?

For a consistent behavior you should consider using a Constructor and a Destructor:

```
struct lipid{
    // constructor
    lipid() {
        this->head = new bead;
        this->body = new bead;
        this->tail = new bead;
    }
    // destructor
    ~lipid() {
        delete this->head;
        delete this->body;
        delete this->tail;
    }
    ... // rest of the class
```

Answer (score 2):

You **should not** be using Raw pointers in the first place.
Use **[Smart pointers & RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395123/raii-and-smart-pointers-in-c)**, which is the best solution to the problem you are encountering. Using Smart pointers would ensure that the objects themselves will take care of deallocation once no pointer is referencing them anymore.

Have a look at **[shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm)**.

As far as the source code you posted, You never deallocate the dynamically allocated objects, and hence the memory leak.

Comment: why do you recommend a shared_ptr when there is no obvious sharing going on?

Comment: @daramarak: Because OP states `I should state that I'm pushing the beads and the lipids into (several) vectors.`

Comment: I missed that one. So I see your point. Although one should be careful with shared ownership, as it is something that in my opinion seldom needed, and has drawbacks esp. with excessive use.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you have a leak; you aren't freeing your memory.

Define a destructor in the lipid class that destroys the beads, and when you are storing the dynamically allocated lipids in a vector, use **RAII** with a `shared_ptr` or similar.

Better, use `shared_ptr`s for everything. Or even just use the stack; from the design you have given there's not really any need for pointers anyway (particularly naked pointers)

Answer (score 1):

From your code, I suppose that what Valgrind is trying to tell you is that you have memory leaks.

After allocating some object on the heap:

```
lipid * l = new lipid;
l->head = new bead;
l->body = new bead;
l->tail = new bead;
```

you should also `delete` them appropriately to recover memory. Indeed, you lipid class is missing a destructor where you do clean up... you might try with something like this:

```
struct lipid{
  particle mainPart;
  bead * head;
  bead * body;
  bead * tail;
  ~lipid() {
      delete head;
      delete body;
      delete tail;
  }
  ...
};
```

and use it like this:

```
 lipid * l = new lipid;
l->head = new bead;
l->body = new bead;
l->tail = new bead;

...

//-- when you are done with lipid:
delete l;
```

Comment: Why then, when I don't create the beads but only the lipid there is no leak?

Comment: where you deleting the `l` lipid?

Comment: I don't delete them, they are kept till the end of the run. I added a destructor to the ``lipid`` and it works. I have added a section to me question which is the reason I found this error in the first place