# Can pointers be used in pure C++?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I read `pointer` as ornament of `C` that makes `C` a special language. However, i also used pointers in C++. I guess there are some limitations while using pointer in C++ than in C. As  pointers are data types of C. If i am asked to write a program in pure `C++`, can i use pointers ?

Comment: C++ *is* an extension of C. It's even a superset of it for the most part (there are a few noticeable features C++ doesn't support, and a few more if you consider C99, but the vast majority of C works unchanged for C++, including pointers). Where did you get contrary information?

Comment: I mean to sequel version. Sorry for that. I will edit that one.

Comment: Actually, pointers came from indirect addressing in assembly language, so they are not really particular to just C.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ofcourse you can use pointers in C++. There are some instances where pointers are the only way out. For eg: to use dynamic memory allocations.

One special thing about pointers in C++ is C++ provides **[Smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395123/raii-and-smart-pointers-in-c)** which can make your life easier. Prefer them over raw c like pointers.

Bottomline is:
Use what suits your implementation needs. Don't adhere to fixed rules there are none really.

Comment: @Nim: Was just about adding that.

Comment: ...figured it was the first iteration of the answer... :)

Comment: *C++11* provides smart pointers.  C++03 just provides `auto_ptr`.

Comment: @Nim: Needed a wee bit to lookup the relevant link actually :)

Comment: @dan04: The discussion is not about which standard provides which smart pointer or the history of those, for a user migrating from C to C++ it is important to be made aware of the concept of Smart pointers and RAII, I would rather not confuse a new user with historic semantics.But the additional information added is welcome anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Yep. In fact, for more complex programs, it's quite possible that there simply isn't any other way: if you need to do any kind of dynamic allocation (the kind you do with `new`), you'll get a pointer.

Also, C++ really is an extension of C. Most (if not all) valid C code is also valid C++ code. That's for example one of the reasons C++ has a struct keyword: it needs to be backwards compatible with C.

Comment: From where we are standing right now we ougth to say C++03 is similar to c89 with subtle differences. C99 have diverged a lot.