# Why (or when) should I separate declaration and assignment?

Tags: language-agnostic, constructor

My IDE constantly says me to do this. I vaguely remember I've read in some C++ paper that has something to do with exceptions in constructors.

Java example:

```
    void foo(){
        String result = "";
        int i = 5; // should this ever be a problem ?
    }
```

For both lines IDE suggests to separate.

**Additional questions**

**1.** is there difference if I create by value or by reference. 
E.g. in C++ `class A{}; ... A a = ...;` vs `A* a = new...;`

**2.** my guess it's never a problem with basic types such as `int` or `float`. Are [POD's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) the same ?

Comment: You have tagged your question language-agnostic, but it is indeed very language-specific. Please make up your mind.

Comment: @Björn: that's because I'm not sure what the problem is. I thought it's similar in Java and C# (and probably other managed langs), and in C++, D, Delphi (and probably other, where manual management is possible). So decided to restrict it to langs with constructors. Do you think I should retag it with those 5 tags ?

Comment: I think as it stands, the scope of the question is too big. The answer would require a detailed explanation for each of the languages, as they are all very different in how they handle exceptions and object-construction/-initialization.

Comment: @Björn: Anyway, I want to know this at least about Delphi, Java and C++. Even if it's gonna be several answers, it's ok. So, I will keep things as they are for some time and see where it goes.

Answer (score 0):

#### This answer deals with C++, behaviors in other languages might be different

You actually should initialize your variables when you declare them.

For `POD` types, this is just to so you don't forget to initialize them and thus use uninitialized data.

For user types, this is done for optimization:

```
A other;

//this will first construct a, and then assign a new value to a
//the initial construction is useless and takes up processing time
A a;
a = other;

//b is only initialized once
A b = other;
```

1) That's not creating a variable by value or reference. It's creating it on the stack or on the heap. There are differences which are explained in **a lot** of posts here on SO.

2) It's not a problem, it's more of a habbit for POD's. The main reason why initialization is done in the same line as the declaration was explained in the first lines of the answer.

Comment: If you want to know how this relates to exception-safety, read about [RAII](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395123/raii-and-smart-pointers-in-c).

Comment: IIUC, your `"2) It's not a problem, it's more of a habbit for POD's"` is not correct. C++ will call (auto-generated) default c'tor anyway, i.e. it has nothing to do with habits. (I'm reviewing my non-accepted Q's, please don't take it as nit-picking)