# How to pass a vector of pointers so as to change them in the function?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm basically trying to pass by reference, so that the changes wrought by the function upon the vector are permanent outside the scope of the function. Am I correct in thinking that passing a vector of pointers is sufficient to accomplish this on its own? It makes complete sense in my head, but I just want to confirm I'm not making an error here somehow.

```
void updateCursors(vector<cursor*> cursors)
```

This should be sufficient to change the data in the objects pointed to by these pointers, yes?

Comment: Do you want to make changes to the `std::vector` itself, or only to the elements?

Comment: Or only to the referands of the elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the vector by reference -

```
vector<cursor*>& cursors
```

But you should not be holding pointers in a vector. The recommended way is to hold objects that are copyable/movable -

```
vector<cursor>& cursors
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with holding pointers in a vector - or any other container so long as the ownership and lifecycle is carefully managed, particularly in C++03.

Comment: Yeah, they exist as pointers because it's dynamically allocated.

Answer (score 1):

***"This should be sufficient to change the data in the objects pointed to by these pointers, yes?"***
When you pass a vector to this function, copy will be created (since it's passing by value), but since it's vector of pointers, **YES**, changes to objects will be visible outside.

But it would be still better to pass it by reference so that redundant copy is not created:

```
void updateCursors(vector<cursor*>& cursors)
```

Also note, that there's ugly memory management connected with using naked pointers. I suggest you use vector of objects if possible (`vector<cursor>`) or if you really have a good reason to use pointers, then I suggest you to use smart pointers (`shared_ptr<cursor>` instead of `cursor*`). This question could help you: [RAII and smart pointers in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/395123/1168156)