# How does ptr_vector manage memory?

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost

I'm currently getting myself into c++ for lower level coding with opengl. I come from a heavy objc background so I have some understanding about memory management but I can't seem to get how the "boost" library manages container types like `ptr_vector`.

I think my problem is related to the fact that I have no idea how `ptr_vector` manages the destruction of itself and its objects.

Please take a look at the following code:

```
// Header file
...
ptr_vector<IObject3D> objects;
...

// Implementation file
...
void ApplicationEngine::init()
{
    WavefrontObject3D *object = new WavefrontObject3D("Ninja.obj");
    objects.push_back(object); 
}
...
```

**So, for the actually question**: am I creating a leak here through the "object" variable?

I'm used to retain and release my objects manually with explicit calls in objc:
previously I had to `alloc init` the WavefrontObject3D `object`, add it to an array and afterwards `release` that same object to avoid leaks.

But when I add a `delete object` after the `push_back` call the deconstructor of the WavefrontObject3D `object` is called. This gives me a hint that the `ptr_vector` isn't retaining the `object` variable. Is my assumption correct?

**Additional, but related, question:** let's say I want to destroy the containing class `ApplicationEngine` don't I have to call some kind of deconstructor on the `ptr_vector` or the elements it manages?

Comment: `But when I add a delete object after the push_back call the deconstructor of the WavefrontObject3D object is called.` Well that is what `delete` is made for. It calls the destructor on the instance the pointer points to.

Comment: I think you should read up on [RAII](http://stackoverflow.com/q/395123/20984), which is the way most memory management is done in so-called "modern" c++.

Comment: Great resource @LucTouraille! Exactly the way I wanted to approach c++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this doesn't create a leak. All `ptr_*` containers will delete objects that are stored in them when the container goes out of scope.

If you delete the object after adding it to the container, you will create `undefined behavior` as the container will attempt to delete it again.

Additional question: No, if you store the `ptr_vector` by value its lifetime is managed by the scope of the surrounding class.

Let's write a simple implementation of `ptr_vector`. It has no support for indirect iterators and custom deleters and a lot of other things but shows the principles used.

```
template <typename T>
class ptr_vector {
public:
  // assume control over it
  void push_back(T* x) 
  { if(x) c_.push_back(x); else throw bad_pointer(); }

  ~ptr_vector() { 
    // delete everything that is stored here
    for(auto x : c_)  delete x;
  }
private:
  std::vector<T*> c_;
};


// a user class
struct user_class {
  void addSomething() { x.push_back(new int(23)); }
  ptr_vector<int> x;
};
```

If user class goes out of scope, the destructor of `ptr_vector` will
be called and all memory will be reclaimed. No leak in sight.

Answer (score 2):

```
void push_back( T* x );
```

> Requirements: x != 0 Effects: Inserts the pointer into container and
>   takes ownership of it Throws: bad_pointer if x == 0 Exception safety:
>   Strong guarantee

```
template
    < 
        class T, 
        class CloneAllocator = heap_clone_allocator,
        class Allocator      = std::allocator<void*>
    >
    class ptr_vector : public ptr_sequence_adapter
                              <
                                  T,
                                  std::vector<void*,Allocator>,
                                  CloneAllocator
                              >
```

So you can specify your own `CloneAllocator` and not delete elements that stored in ptr_vector, but `heap_clone_allocator` (default par for `CloneAllocator`) deletes all stored elements in destructor.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/reference.html#class-heap-clone-allocator

Answer (score 0):

`ptr_vector` will free all the elements in its destructor, so you don't have to do anything more than what you already do, that is, create the objects, add them to the `ptr_vector`, and leave the management to it. Calling `delete` explicitly will make the object destroyed twice (once when you request it and again when the `ptr_vector` finishes). In other words, `ptr_vector` does not duplicate the object.

When the `ApplicationEngine` finishes, if it has an instance of the `ptr_vector`, the destructor of that vector will be called, that in turn deletes the added objects.

Answer (score 0):

ptr_containers [own the memory pointed at by the pointer you pass to it.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/conventions.html#whenever-pointers-are-inserted-into-a-container-ownership-is-transferred-to-the-container)
Read [the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/conventions.html) for more info on cloneable concepts.