# How to create a serial port without opening it, using boost

Tags: c++, linux, boost, serial-port

Been searching the google and SO, but i seem to be unable to find the solution.

```
boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::serial_port> port (new boost::asio::serial_port(*ioService, "/dev/ttyS1"));
```

This way the port is created and opened right away, and thats not what i want, i need to create it now, but set all the options and open it later. How can i do that?

I read in the manual and `basic_serial_port` seems to have a constructor that creates a port by just using the ioService, however, im not sure how to go about it and use it for my application.

Answer (score 2):

One of the Right Things to do in C++ is [RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395123/raii-and-smart-pointers-in-c) (Resource Acquisition is Initialisation), and it's the right thing to do for lots of good reasons -  so I think you probably *shouldn't* do what you're trying to.

Could you pass around a `nullptr` / null smart pointer to the serial port until you're actually going to open it?

Comment: While i cna't mark this as accepted answer because it doesn't really answer my direct question, i did rewrite the code of my app so that i get all the required data about port settings before creating the port. Thus, i create and open the port along with the object that owns it and close it when the objects is destroyed.