# Improving RAI template class on Windows' handles?

Tags: c++

So, in the answer of this question [Proper way close WinAPI HANDLEs (avoiding of repeated closing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028872/proper-way-close-winapi-handles-avoiding-of-repeated-closing) the answerer creates a HandleWrapper template, which you can use like this:

```
HandleWrapper<KernelHandleTraits> hFile(CreateFile(...))
```

and hFile will be destroyed when it gets out of scope.

In your code there also may be lines similar to this:

```
ReadFile(hFile(), ...)
```

I am wondering how the template or class for a Handle would look like, if I wanted to use it like this:

```
ReadFile(hFile, ...)
```

Note the missing parenthesis. Is there any C++ trick to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is: You would have to implement a [conversion operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator), i.e. `operator HANDLE()`, that returns the stored handle.<sup>*</sup>

Nothing I'd recommend. There's enough invisible code in C++ already. No need to add to it, less so when there is so little to be had.

---

<sup>*</sup> *Incidentally, the code you linked to already implements the appropriate conversion operator, `operator traits::HandleType()`. In other words: You don't need to implement anything in particular to use your favored syntax.*

Comment: Okaay. I have got mixed up the conversion operator with the function (functor) operator..

Comment: @J.Doe: A `HANDLE` is trivially copy-constructible, and passed by value into the `ReadFile()` call. No copy-c'tor is executed. The destructor runs, when `hFile` goes out of scope.

Comment: What if CreateFile returned a bool instead of a handle. And the handle would be stored in a pointer to a handle. Something like this: if (CreateFile(&handle, "filename", ...)) {..}      in this case how could I use the "nice" syntax?

Comment: @J.Doe: A function that takes a pointer to a handle usually does so, because that **is** the return value. In that case you need to pass a pointer to a plain handle, and attach a resource management object once it returns. RAII wrappers often provide an `attach()` member for that, or have a constructor taking a handle value. The implementation you linked to has neither, and you would have to extend it.