# Is memory freed when dynamic array goes out of scope

Tags: c++, scope, dynamic-arrays, dynamic-allocation

I am dynamically allocating memory for an array in a function. My question is: once the function finishes running is the memory freed?

code:

```
void f(){
    cv::Mat* arr = new cv::Mat[1];
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm fixing the problem by not using heap.

Comment: General rule: exactly one `delete` for each `new`, exactly one `delete[]` for each `new[]`.

Comment: Or better yet... all calls to new assigned to a smart pointer and *no* explicit calls to delete! ;)

Comment: @BleepBloop Can you please explain what a smart pointer is?

Comment: @Aly See my response. Smart pointers (look up `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` are classes that act like pointers, but also automatically delete their memory when they go out of scope.

Comment: Here is a related question about smart pointers which might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395123/raii-and-smart-pointers-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not. You must free it by calling

```
delete[] arr;
```

But you should ask yourself whether it is necessary to allocate dynamically. This would require no explicit memory management:

```
void f(){
    cv::Mat arr[1];
    ...
}
```

If you need a dynamically sized array, you could use an `std::vector`. The vector will internally allocate dynamically, but will take care of de-allocating it's resources:

```
void f(){
    std::vector<cv::Mat> arr(n); // contains n cv::Mat objects
    ...
}
```

Comment: However, you also can't dynamically size the array (at least within the C++ standard - I know gcc provides dynamically-sized arrays as an extension).

Comment: @slavik262 Thanks. I added an example with `vector`. Although OP's example uses the compile time constant `1`.

Answer (score 6):

No, memory allocated using `new` is not automatically freed when the pointer goes out of scope.

However, you can (and *should*) use C++11's `unique_ptr`, which handles freeing the memory when it goes out of scope:

```
void f(){
    std::unique_ptr<cv::Mat[]> arr(new cv::Mat[1]);
    ...
}
```

C++11 also provides `shared_ptr` for pointers you might want to copy. Modern C++ should strive to use these "smart pointers", as they provide safer memory management with almost no performance hit.

Comment: no C++11 for me :(, I installed gcc using apt-get which I assumed would give me the latest and greatest but it appears unique_ptr does not exist for me

Comment: @Aly, When you invoke `g++`, try `g++ -std=c++11` or `g++ -std=c++0x`. One of these should enable `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 4):

No.  Every call to `new` needs to be matched up with a call to `delete` somewhere.

In your case `arr` *iteself* is a variable with automatic storage duration.  This means that `arr` *itself* will be destroyed when it goes out of scope.  However the thing that `arr` points to does not, because *that* is a variable that does not have autoatic storage duration.

The fact that `arr` itself has automatic storage duration can be used to your advantage, by wrapping the raw pointer in a class that destroys the stored pointer when the automatic object is destroyed.  This object utilizes an idion known as [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) to implement a so-called "smart pointer".  Since this is a very common requirement in well-designed applications, the C++ Standard Library provides a number of smart pointer classes which you can use.  In C++03, you can use

`std::auto_ptr`

In C++11 `auto_ptr` has been deprecated and replaced by several other better smart pointers.  Among them:

`std::unique_ptr`
`std::shared_ptr`

In general, it is a good idea to use smart pointers instead of raw ("dumb") pointers as you do here.

If what you ultimately need are dynamically-sized arrays, as supported by C99, you should know that C++ does not have direct support for them.  Some compilers (notably GCC) do provide support for dynamically sized arrays, but these are compiler-specific language extensions.  In order to have something that approximates a dynamically sized array while using only portable, Standards-compliant code, why not use a `std::vector`?

**Edit:** *Assigning to an array:*

In your comments you describe the way in which you assign to this array, which I have taken to mean something like this:

```
int* arr = new int[5];
arr[1] = 1;
arr[4] = 2;
arr[0] = 3;
```

If this is the case, you can accomplish the same using `vector` by calling `vector::operator[]`.  Doing this looks uses very similar syntax to what you've used above.  The one real "gotcha" is that since `vector`s are dyanamically sized, you need to make sure the `vector` has at least `N` elements before trying to assign the element at position `N-1`.  This can be accomplished in a number of ways.

You can create the `vector` with `N` items from the get-go, in which case each will be value-initialized:

```
vector<int> arr(5); // creates a vector with 5 elements, all initialized to zero
arr[1] = 1;
arr[4] = 2;
arr[0] = 3;
```

You can `resize` the vector after the fact:

```
vector<int> arr; // creates an empty vector
arr.resize(5); // ensures the vector has exactly 5 elements
arr[1] = 1;
arr[4] = 2;
arr[0] = 3;
```

Or you can use a variety of algorithms to fill the vector with elements.  One such example is `fill_n`:

```
vector<int> arr; // creates empty vector
fill_n(back_inserter(arr), 5, 0);  // fills the vector with 5 elements, each one has a value of zero
arr[1] = 1;
arr[4] = 2;
arr[0] = 3;
```

Comment: Hi, I am not using a vector because I am assigning to the array in a random manner. i.e if array is size 5 I may set arr[3] followed by arr[1] etc. when I tried this with vectors it just terminated the program with no exception :(. I don't appear to have C++11 can you please provide a code sample to use std::auto_ptr (I'm very new to c++).

Comment: @Aly:  You can assign to a `vector` as you have described, if I understand you correctly.  See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

No, of course not.

*For every `new` you need precisely one `delete`.*

*For every `new[]` you need precisely one `delete[]`.*

Since you don't have the matching `delete[]`, your program is broken.

(For that reason, the adult way of using C++ is not to use `new` or pointers at all. Then you don't have those problems.)

Comment: "For that reason, the adult way of using C++ is not to use new or pointers at all. Then you don't have those problems." What? Are you suggesting to never use the heap?

Comment: @slavik262: Of course not. But I'm strongly encouraging not to use the so-called heap **manually**! Library functions are better at that, and safer.

Comment: Using `new` is certainly fine if you wrap it in C++11 smart pointers - there's plenty of instances where you would need to allocate your own memory outside of a library you're using.

Comment: @JohnDibling: Just for reasons of exception safety alone, `new` calls should go into a very restricted set of auxiliary functions such as `make_unique`.

Comment: @KerrekSB:  Setting aside the pedantry of there being no `make_unique` in the Standard Library, I don't disagree.

Answer (score 1):

No. The array the allocated on the heap, you'll have to delete it before it goes out of scope:

```
void f() {

    cv::Mat * arr = new cv::Mat[1];

    // ...

    delete [] arr;

}
```

Comment: New C++ code should try to avoid using `delete` explicitly - `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` do it automatically and provide better ownership semantics.