# Ensuring C++ Object is properly de-allocated

Tags: c++, oop

I am beginning to teach myself C++ and how to handle objects without a garbage collector is causing me some confusion.  Here is a simple case of what I am trying to do:

```
A* a;
B b = new B(a);    // Note that B is a derived class of A
a = &b;

while (a != NULL)
{
    (*a).run();
}
```

This all works as I expect it to.  Where I am having the issue, is that inside the run() method of B, I want to do something like:

```
C c = new C(a);  // a is the same pointer as above, that has been stored 
                 // and C another derived class from A
a = &c;
```

and then let run() exit.  The while loop in the first block would then call would call run() on the new object.  My question is, how do I make sure that the memory from the original b is correctly de-allocated?

Comment: You don't need to allocate everything via `new`. It's perfectly fine (and actually preferable) to just declare the variable like so: `B b;` or `C c;`. If the object needs to exist outside its current scope, use [smart pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395123/raii-and-smart-pointers-in-c).

Comment: Most of the above code fails to compile.  In C++ objects and pointers to objects are not the same.

Comment: I have found that I was greatly overcomplicating what I was trying to do.  I simply made run() return type A and am avoiding pointers altogether.  Considering I asked about deallocation though, the answers were insightful.  @Yakk, what were the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `std::shared_ptr` in this case. If two classes have members which need to point to the same object, then you can make both of them `shared_ptr`. And you do this usually, however if while doing so, if you about to create cyclic-dependency, then to break that cyclic-dependency, you need `std::weak_ptr`.

Here is example of `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr`.

**WRONG CODE (cyclic-dependency):**

```
struct B;

struct A
{
   std::shared_ptr<B> bp;
}

struct B
{
   std::shared_ptr<A> ba;  //this creates a cyclic dependency.
}
```

**CORRECT CODE (non-cyclic):**

```
struct B;

struct A
{
   std::shared_ptr<B> bp;
}

struct B
{
   std::weak_ptr<A> ba;  //break cyclic dependency with std::weak_ptr
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you're faced with dynamic memory allocation and nontrivial ownership semantics, smart pointers are often a good way to ensure correctness.

See, for example, [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).