# C++: linked list head and tail pointers

Tags: c++, linked-list

I don´t get this, when I call `head->value`it returns me the last value added to the linked list. Should it not return me the first item since `head` is only set when it is empty? correct? I am thinking maybe there is there some other bug in the code.

```
void LinkedListPQueue::enqueue(const string& elem) {
    cell *newCell = new cell;
    newCell->value = elem;
    newCell->next = NULL;
    if(this->isEmpty()) {
        this->head = this->tail = newCell;
    } else {
        // find smallest and put it there

        this->tail->next = newCell;
        this->tail = newCell;
    }
}
```

declared in header

```
struct cell {
    std::string value;
    cell *next;
};
cell *head, *tail;
```

Comment: There's no `this->value` in the code you've shown. Post a small but complete program that shows the problem.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code line by line in a debugger? Are you sure the problem lies in this `enqueue` function, and not the function where you print the values or somewhere else?

Comment: // find smallest and put it there -> That is the important part, without that nobody can help directly. But I'm pretty sure, there is the problem. Also take a look at your isEmpty().

Comment: @Peter I guess there is no more code there. `this->tail->next = newCell;this->tail = newCell;` is enough.

Comment: If you are going to implement your own datastructures then I strongly recommend you to have a look at the [RAII](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395123/raii-and-smart-pointers-in-c) and [copy-swap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) posts.

Comment: @Peter: They are notes to self.

Comment: Okay. But what means "find smallest" - that doesn't make sense in the context. And whatever your "counting", I'm pretty sure your shouldn't do that in a linked-list.

Answer (score 6):

My be `isEmpty` is not implemented correctly so everytime you add a new node you re-assign the head  to that node

Comment: Actually you are correct, I forgot updating the counter. I am a beginner on the use of pointers and linked list, so that´s why I thought initially it was a problem there

Comment: @pmr unless you can think of another alternative, guessing from set of 1 is 100% sure

Comment: @TomLilletveit: `bool isEmpty(){return null==head;}`. No counters.

Comment: @Agent_L It's beginner C++ code. I can think of a thousand alternatives.

Comment: Agent_L: That´s what I thought as well, it´s a linked list - it needs lots of pointers.

Comment: @pmr: this does not make the answer less insightful

Comment: @Agent_L I'm sorry you didn't see the humor. You are right, all pointers here are needed. Still, this should be a comment and not an answer (guesses, even educated ones, belong there). OP should provide a minimal example exhibiting the problem before this is actually answerable.

Comment: @pmr You're right about that - it should be a comment. Hassan gambled and won.