# C++ pointer and reference

Tags: c++, class, pointers, reference

In my C++ class I need to assign a method with pointer and/or reference. So I do this tricky thing :

(Assuming **aclass** is a class variable AnotherClass *)

```
void MyClass::setElem(AnotherClass *pVal)
{
  aclass = pVal;
}

void MyClass::setElem(AnotherClass &refVal)
{
  aClass = &article;
}
```

But in my opinion, sounds not so "graceful"...

Better way to achieve this ?

Comment: I don't see how else you'd do it?  Maybe you are not really explaining what you are after

Comment: It works perfectly. But to do it better we need to know WHY you do it

Comment: Brother: please uncomment  *`Assuming aclass is a class variable AnotherClass *aclass;`*

Comment: You have removed information don't remove.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - why you don't yourself do what edit you want to do?

Comment: @user93353 :) :) .....

Comment: "In my opinion, sounds not so "graceful"..." Why? What is it that you don't like about it? Apart from using different function names, I don't know how this could be improve - without taking a wider look at your design.

Comment: Well, now that we're at it, you can just delete the reference version altogether and just call your pointer version with the address of the reference, i.e. setElem(&refVal) in your calling code.

Comment: In any case, this code is not RAII-compliant so you absolutely need to document who owns the pointer. And you'd take advantage of rethinking your design altogether to make it follow RAII. See [What is meant by Resource Acquisition is Initialization (RAII)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2321511/96780) and [RAII and smart pointers in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/395123/96780) for more info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
void MyClass::setElem(AnotherClass *pVal)
{
  aclass = pVal;
}

void MyClass::setElem(AnotherClass &refVal)
{
  setElem(&refVal);
}
```

Is this graceful enough? As Mr. Pitt once said in Seinfeld "Well, you don't want too much grace or you won't be able to stand".

Comment: It is... And I agree with Mr Seinfeld too ;)