# Does deleting dynamically allocated std::string using a pointer returned by c_str() cause a memory leak in C++?

Tags: c++, string, memory-management, memory-leaks, return-value

I'm writing a function to load a txt file and return a const char* 
the function below works, my question is will this function cause a memory leak if I don't store *pS and then call delete pS ?

```
const char* loadFile(string fname)
{
   string line,text;
   ifstream in(fname);
   while(std::getline(in, line))
   {
       text += line + "\n";
   }

   string *pS = new string(text);
   const char* data = pS->c_str();

   return data;
}
```

the function is used in my code as follows

```
static const char* pVS;
...
pVS = loadFile("VS.txt");
...
delete pVS;
```

Will this delete the string ?

Comment: std::string is **NOT** simply a wrapper around a char* buffer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*"Will this delete the string ?"*

**No.** It will try to delete `std::string`'s underlying character storage yielding  an *undefined behavior*.
Even if it successfully freed that storage, there are other `std::string`'s members that it wouldn't take care of, so yes, apart from *undefined behavior*, there's a *memory leak* as well.

Solution: Change your function to return `std::string` object instead. Alternativelly you might return `std::vector<std::string>` containing lines, which seems more reasonable than adding `"\n"`.

---

To avoid memory leaks:

- avoid dynamic allocation always when it is possible and
- when it's not possible and you have to use `new` or `new[]`, then make sure that:

  - for every `new` there's an appropriate `delete` call and
  - for every `new[]` there's an appropriate `delete[]` call.

  (note that this might be harder than it seems... especially when you're dealing with error-prone code while you still need to take care of every possible return path ~ that's one of the main reasons why it is always preferable to use [RAII and smart pointers in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/395123/1168156))

Comment: @ExpatEgghead: What do you mean with `*sP` ?

Comment: This will not per se try to delete the `string`'s internal storage, as the pointer `data` is undefined when it is returned.

Comment: @rubenvb: [`std::string::c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) returns *"Pointer to the underlying character storage."*

Comment: @rubenvb: I'm not sure what you mean with *"pointer data is undefined when it is returned"*... note that he did `new std::string`

Comment: Moreover, pointer returned by `c_str()` might not point to dynamically allocated buffer at all.

Comment: @jrok: Well, that's one of the main reason why `delete str.c_str()` causes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @LihO Right, I was a bit too strict on `c_str()`. I reread `<string>` in the n3337 and this usage is fine, if not leaky.

Answer (score 1):

This function does indeed cause a memory leak, and the use in code you've shown will invoke Undefined Behaviour to boot.

The function causes a leak because you dynamically allocate a `std::string` (the one you store in `pS`) and then lose its address once `loadFile` returns. There's no way to deallocate this string any more, so it's leaked.

This code:

```
pVS = loadFile("VS.txt");
...
delete pVS;
```

is even worse. You're obtaining a pointer which you have not allocated via `new` (it came from `c_str()`), and you're calling `delete` on it. That's undefined behaviour (most likely memory corruption), pure and simple.

The correct thing to do would be to change the function and just return the `std::string`:

```
string loadFile(string fname)
{
   string line,text;
   ifstream in(fname);
   while(std::getline(in, line))
   {
       text += line + "\n";
   }
   return text;
}
```

If and when the caller needs a `const char*` out of this, they can call `c_str()` themselves.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid the memory leak and Undefined Behavior, instead of returning a `char*`, return a `string`.

```
std::string loadFile(string fname)
{
  // ...
   string retval (text);
   // ...
   return retval;
}
```

This returns a `string` by value, but under optimization the compiler will often elide the copy.

If you absolutely *must* return a `char*`, then do it right:

```
const char* loadFile(string fname)
{
   string line,text;
   ifstream in(fname);
   while(std::getline(in, line))
   {
       text += line + "\n";
   }

   string retval(text);
   char* data = new char [retval.length()+1];
   strcpy (retval.c_str(), data);
   return data;
}
```

Remember that on the other side of this you will have to `delete` this pointer, which means using `delete []`:

```
int main()
{
  const char* data = loadFile (...);
  delete [] data;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that in the second case, the correct cleanup would be `delete[]`, not `delete`.

Comment: @Agnew:  Yeah, I left all the client-side stuff out but I'll add it in.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
return strdup(text.c_str());
```

The result is deletable. When you return a char* you won't be able to avoid doing your own memory management. Way better way would be to just return an `std::string`.

Comment: The result is not deletable.  It is freeable.

Comment: `strdup` is not in standard C nor in standard C++. It's a POSIX thing.