# C++ delete [] object causes crash

Tags: c++, class, object, crash, delete-operator

I made a dynamic array of objects. When I call delete[] , program crashes and stops responding. But it does strange behavior: calls all destructors and crashes. look at this code and output. All the memory for all arrays is allocated.

```
//main file
#include "myobject.h"

int size;
myObject *foo;

//some operations to estimate size

foo = new myObject[size];

//some operations with myObject

std::cout<<"size: "<<size<<"\n";
std::cout<<"Deleting object\n";

size=0;
delete [] foo;
```

Next file:

```
//myobject.h

class myObject
{
    public:
    int number;

    Object1 ob1[64]
    Object2 *ob2;

    myObject(){ };
    ~myObject()
    {
        std::cout<<"delete "<<number<<"\n";

        delete [] ob1;
        delete [] ob2;
    };
}
```

And the output:

```
size: 11

Deleting object

delete 10

delete 9

delete 8

delete 7

delete 6

delete 5

delete 4

delete 3

delete 2

delete 1

delete 0
```

And then it crashes and stops responding.

Comment: How is `ob2` allocated ?

Comment: Why do you delete ob1 in te destructor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only call `delete[]` on pointers returned by `new[]`, and you must do this exactly once. The same applies for `delete` and `new`.

Particularly, you cannot `delete[] obj1` because it is a built in array, not a pointer, and `obj2` only if it points to not-freed memory allocated with `new[]`.

Answer (score 6):

```
delete [] ob1;
```

You didn't `new obj1`; it's an array contained in the object. Deleting anything that wasn't allocated with `new` gives undefined behaviour, which might well be a crash.

If you're going to juggle pointers like this, then you'll need to learn about the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722) to avoid the next deathtrap you'll encounter. Then learn about [RAII and smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395123), and forget about this dangerous nonsense.