# Fixing collision memory leak in std::map

Tags: c++, performance, dictionary, memory-leaks

I encountered this kind of issue: a *possible* memory leak.
Imagine if you store two different heap pointers for same key.

```
#include <map>

std::map<int, int*> myMap;

void Store(int key, int* value)
{
    myMap[key] = value;
}

int main()
{
   Store(42, new int(42));
   Store(35, new int(35));
   delete myMap[42];
   delete myMap[35];
}
```

I thought about fixing that way:

```
#include <map>

std::map<int, int*> myMap;

void Store(int key, int* value)
{
    auto it = myMap.find(key);
    if (it != myMap.end()))
    {
        delete it->second;
        it->second = value;
    }
    else
    {
        myMap[key] = value;
    }
}

int main()
{
   Store(42, new int(42));
   Store(35, new int(35));
   delete myMap[42];
   delete myMap[35];
}
```

But there are two logarithmic look-ups instead of one now...
Then I thought about this following code,

```
#include <map>

std::map<int, int*> myMap;

void Store(int key, int* value)
{
    auto& mappedValue = myMap[key];
    if (mappedValue == nullptr)
    {
        mappedValue = value;
    }
    else
    {
        delete mappedValue;
        mappedValue = value;
    }
}

int main()
{
   Store(42, new int(42));
   Store(35, new int(35));
   delete myMap[42];
   delete myMap[35];
}
```

but how can I be certain mappedValue will always point to nullptr if there is no associated value ?
What would you suggest to tackle memory leak and stick with logarithmic complexity ?
**EDIT**: refactoring is very costy, I'm looking for a solution without smart pointers.

Comment: Why are you storing an `int*` and not just an `int`?

Comment: This is legacy code. Refactoring is very costy.

Comment: "a possible memory leak." You can strengthen that statement. The first piece of code as a *definite* memory leak.

Comment: Ok sorry for misleading code I posted, I'm editing it now.

Comment: the non-use of smart pointers led you here, which had a time cost. Every change you make will require debugging and tests to prove correct deallocation (and non-use of deallocated objects). Refactoring to use a smart pointer will eventually prove to be an order of magnitude *less* costly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but how can I be certain mappedValue will always point to nullptr if there is no associated value ?

If `operator[]` adds a new element it is [value-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). For non-class types as pointers are this is equivalent to zero-initialization which in turn is a `nullptr` in case of pointers. See [`std::map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at).

Comment: Wonderful, is this stated as is in Standard ?

Comment: For value-initialization see §8.5 8.4, zero-initialization is §8.5 6.1 (§4.10 1 states *A null pointer constant is an integer literal (2.13.2) with value zero*) (from N4296)

Comment: @LeFlou: §23.4.4.3: *`T& operator[](const key_type& x);` (...) If there is no key equivalent to `x` in the map, inserts `value_type(x, T())` into the map.*

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using the [RAII in the form of smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395123/raii-and-smart-pointers-in-c), and instead define your map as

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>

std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<int>> myMap;
```

(For this to work make sure to configure your compiler to [c++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) mode.)

Your map becomes something like: map integers to a pointer-like object that will take care of deallocation.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion but I would like to know how to tackle this issue without smart pointers.

Comment: In this case, perhaps you should explain what are the settings causing your reluctance to use shared pointers.

Comment: I posted a tiny part of the code, revamped for SO. Refactoring is very costy, I'm looking for another way.

Answer (score 1):

With the new standard c++11, `std::unique_ptr` is your friend. It has no overhead whatsoever, and provides memory safety:

```
std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<int>> myMap;

void Store(int key, int* value)
{
    myMap[key] = std::unique_ptr<int>{value};
}

int main()
{
   Store(42, new int(42));
   Store(35, new int(35));
}
```

No memory leak with that.
If you have access to c++14, you could even do this:

```
std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<int>> myMap;

void Store(int key, std::unique_ptr<int> value)
{
    myMap[key] = std::move(value);
}

int main()
{
   Store(42, std::make_unique<int>(42));
   Store(35, std::make_unique<int>(35));
}
```

No new, no delete. No memory leak and safe.

Comment: This answer is good in spirit but has a lot of errors in it. Neither the first nor the second code example compiles. First of all, even without `std::make_unique`, good practice would be instantiating the `std::unique_ptr` immediately, or just writing your own `make_unique` function. `Store` must not take `int*` but `std::unique_ptr<int>`, and the value must then be inserted into the map using `std::move(value)`.

Answer (score 1):

why not using map::insert

```
auto res = myMap.insert(std::make_pair(key,value));
if ( ! res.second ) {
    delete res.first->second;
    res.first->second = value;
}
```

Comment: This is even shorter, I like it.