# Do the same action at the end of the try block and all catch clocks in a try-catch statement

Tags: c++, c++11, try-catch, c++14, code-duplication

Is it a way to avoid code duplication (`FinalAction` function call in all `catch` blocks and in a `try` one)?

```
try
{
    // some actions including creation of new objects
    FinalAction();
}
catch (const Exception1& ex1)
{
    ProcessException1(ex1);
    FinalAction();
}
catch (const Exception2& ex2)
{
    ProcessException2(ex2);
    FinalAction();
}
// ...
catch (const ExceptionN& exN)
{
    ProcessExceptionN(exN);
    FinalAction();
}
catch (...)
{
    ProcessUnknownException();
    FinalAction();
}
```

**Update:** `FinalAction()` should be called *before* the destructors of the objects created in the `try` block. So simple solution like the following one doesn't work here.

```
try
{
    // some actions including creation of new objects
}
catch (const Exception1& ex1)
{
    ProcessException1(ex1);
}
catch (const Exception2& ex2)
{
    ProcessException2(ex2);
}
// ...
catch (const ExceptionN& exN)
{
    ProcessExceptionN(exN);
}
catch (...)
{
    ProcessUnknownException();
}
FinalAction();
```

Some more information about `FinalAction`: it doesn't throw and it doesn't clean any resources allocated in the `try` block.

Comment: Calling the same method from both _try_ and _catch_ suggests code smell. Could you provide us with further details regarding what you're trying to accomplish? Maybe that would help with finding a solution.

Comment: does `FinalAction()` potentially throw? if not just use RAII

Comment: @XavierÁlvarez In fact it is a simple wait for a key press. But it gave me an idea of a generalization.

Comment: @Mgetz How RAII can be used here? A destructor of a RAII object will be called before the first `catch` block as I know.

Comment: @Constructor no it will be called in reverse order of construction when the enclosing scope exits. So if the object holding `FinalAction()` is outside the `try` you're fine

Comment: @Mgetz And if the enclosing scope is a `try` block then it will be called before the first `catch` block.

Comment: Only the first `catch block` *corresponding to that `try`*. Not any random `catch` block associated with a random nested `try`.

Comment: @Puppy All `catch` blocks in my answer are corresponding to the only `try` block.

Comment: @Constructor: Right, but he doesn't want you to put it in the scope of that `try` block. He wants you to put it in the parent scope of that `try` block.

Comment: @Puppy Then it is the same as a simple call of it after all `catch` blocks.

Comment: @Constructor: Your edits have contradicted themselves. Your first statement is that `FinalAction()` must be called at the end of each `catch`. Then you say that `FinalAction()` must be called before destroying any objects in the `try` block. It can't be both, and your former (code-repeating) example *does not* achieve the effect of the latter. So which is it?

Comment: @NicolBolas OK, you are right. `FinalAction()` must be called at the end of `catch` blocks if an exception is thrown. If it is not thrown it should be called at the end of the `try` block before destroying any objects in the `try` block.

Comment: @Constructor: Why the restriction within the try block? After all, `FinalAction` *cannot* be reliant on anything those objects do, since it will be called after they're destroyed in the event of an exception. So I'm not sure how this restriction could be *necessary*.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is just call it after the `try` block.

```
bool success = false;
try
{
    // some actions including creation of new objects
    FinalAction();
    success = true;
}
catch (const Exception1& ex1)
{
    ProcessException1(ex1);
}
if (!success)
    FinalAction();
```

However it's pretty dubious to be doing this instead of using a class to manage whatever resource you're cleaning up with `FinalAction`.

Comment: Thank you for that solution. But it is a bit ugly, isn't it?

Comment: I don't clean any resource with `FinalAction`, it is a simple `wait-for-a-keypress` action.

Comment: @Constructor: It directly expresses the semantic you want- if it threw, do FinalAction.

Comment: @Puppy Yes, I know your solution is appropriate here. I thought to do it in the same manner but decided to search a nicer solution at [SO]. And I haven't found it yet.

Comment: There aren't really any nicer solutions. You need to write the code that does the thing you want it to do. You can't get around that.

Answer (score 1):

Although your question is not an exact duplicate, the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395123/raii-and-smart-pointers-in-c) is appropriate.

What you seem to bee asking for is the equivalent of a `finally`-clause in C++ and the answer is that in C++  this is normally solved through RAII.

I won't repeat the quite extensive answer that was given in the linked SO question, but in summary you make sure that cleanup of resources is done in a destructor. It is likely that your `FinalAction()` is the one that is cleaning up resources right now.

Comment: No, in my question `FinalAction` hasn't nothing with resource cleanup.

Comment: It's a million miles away from even being a vague duplicate, and "the" answer? There are seven!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The _accepted_ answer, the one which has more than twice as many upvotes as number two, gives a good description of RAII. Not knowing what the FinalAction() function did, before the update to the question, "Use RAII" appeared to me to be a good answer.

Comment: @dhavenith: It's a pretty terrible answer. The OP wants to find out how to use RAII to best effect. Just "use RAII" is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know to which classes do *ProcessExceptionX* and *FinalAction* belong or what does *ProcessException* do, but maybe you could have just one *ProcessException* that gets a parameters and executes *FinalAction*, e.g.:

```
...
try {
  FinalAction();
}
catch (const Exception1& ex1) {
  ProcessException(ex1);
}
...

void ProcessException (Exception e) {
 // do things
 FinalAction();
}
```

Comment: No, I can't. `Exception1` ... `ExceptionN` are different exception classes with no common base. And what about handling of unknown exceptions?