# Memory Allocation Exception in Constructor

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a constructor that allocates several blocks of memory using the `new` operator.

```
X::X() {
    a = new int[100];
    b = new char[100];
    c = new float[100];
}
```

My question is, if the allocation of `c` fails, and the constructor throws an exception, will the memory for `a` and `b` be automatically freed?

Comment: No. This is what the technique known as [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) is useful for. If you want a class for managing a dynamic array, it is called [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Don't try to write one yourself.

Comment: Required reading: [Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new)

Comment: Besides the use of `std::vector`, if the size is a compile-time fixed constant, and the memory don't have to allocated from the heap, consider the use of [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead.

Comment: The question should show the types of `a`, `b` and `c`, and you should also clarify whether you mean to ask if the memory will be freed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The memory to which `a` and `b` point would **not** be automatically freed. Every `new[]` must be balanced explicitly with a `delete[]`.

Even if your destructor performed the deletion (assuming `a`, `b`, and `c` are class members), then you'd still leak memory. That's because the destructor **wouldn't** be called in this case since the object failed to construct.

Using `std::vector`s would obviate these problems.

Comment: technically, `a` and `b` are automatically destroyed.  But destroying a pointer doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 9):

`a`, `b`, and `c` will all be destroyed. Depending on what types they are, that might or might not release the memory. If they are pointers their destructors don't do anything, and the memory leaks. If they are some sort of smart pointer, presumably their destructors will release the memory.

Comment: Won't all three data members be destroyed? Their constructors have all finished running by the time the X constructor begins running.

Comment: (Note that the destructors for the data members, if they're raw pointers, won't deallocate the pointers.)

Answer (score 3):

No they won't. This is why you need to learn about [RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/q/395123/2491746) and in particular, containers and smart pointers.

In your case, you can use `std::vector<T>` instead of `new T[100]`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Variable a and b will **not** be automatically destroyed for sure. In your case you must use this **std::vector**. This is because whenever we use a new[] operator for that we need to explicitly define a delete[].