# Using a base class as a safe container for pointers

Tags: c++

So I was looking at this question [Memory Allocation Exception in Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35629737/memory-allocation-exception-in-constructor/35629826#35629826) where my boss states in his beautiful answer that the destructor will not be called.

Which makes me wonder,

If I were to write

```
struct XBase
{
    int* a;
    char* b;
    float* c;

    XBase() : a(nullptr), b(nullptr), c(nullptr) {} 
    ~XBase()
    {
        delete[] a; delete[] b; delete[] c;
    }   
};
```

and

```
struct X : XBase
{
    X() {
        a = new int[100];
        b = new char[100];
        c = new float[100];
    }
}
```

Then, if the allocation of `c` fails (with an exception being thrown), then the destructor of `XBase` would be called, since the base class has been constructed.

And no memory leak?

Am I correct?

Comment: Oh you're so nice. I'm not upvoting though ;-)

Comment: @BoBTFish: Indeed. The fact remains that since you have to even ask this question means that the "solution" is complex.

Comment: You're right. It's a kind of smart pointer which holds multiple raw pointers.

Comment: I may be wrong but as far as I know the destructor of XBase should be declared virtual in order to be called. Please somebody corrects me if this is not true.

Comment: @RobertKock Doesn't have to be; depending on the context.

Comment: @RobertKock: no that is not correct. Indeed we don't have polymorphic types here, but we're not using polymorphism.

Comment: @RobertKock If you destroy an `X` using a pointer to an `XBase`, then the destructor in `XBase` must be virtual, otherwise the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @MSalters: thank you for the edit.

Comment: The design issue is that the inheritance should be private, which also prevents the `X` to `XBase` conversion.

Comment: @P45Imminent The other issue is that if you're copying `X` objects, you have to write additional code, i.e. a copy constructor and assignment operator, to ensure that there are no memory leaks, double-delete's, etc.  So even if you can guarantee that your small example is safe in a toy program, you've got a lot more to code if you actually use this in a real program (unless you disable the copying).  Using `std::vector` alleviates you from having to write this additional code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are right; this *will work*, because:

- By the time `X` constructor body is executed, `XBase` is already constructed, and its destructor will be called.
- Doing `delete` or `delete[]` on null pointers is perfectly valid, and does nothing.

So, if the allocation of `a`, `b` or `c` fails, the destructor of `XBase` will deallocate everything.

But, obviously, this design makes you write much more code that needed, since you can simply use `std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`.

Comment: `c` is defaulted to `nullptr` so it will not crash.

Comment: No, this isn't true; he's setting them to nullptr and it's ok to delete nullptr.

Comment: even with your change I don't see what advantage this brings over my solution

Comment: @P45Imminent you are right, I shouldn't have been in that much hurry.

Answer (score 0):

Just to have a formal version here to back up the claims,

> #### § 15.2/2
>
> An object of any storage duration whose initialization or destruction is terminated by an exception will have destructors executed for all of its fully constructed subobjects [...].

Answer (score -1):

If you're concerned about the memory allocation failing, I would put it in a separate method, like a `Build` or `Create`. You could then let the destructor handle it if it has been initialized (but definitely check pointer before blindly `delete`-ing.

Another solution is smart pointers, which are not designed to fit this case necessarily, but do automatically deallocate their contents.

Comment: The `nullptr` will work fine. I simply meant that in the case of deallocation or other pointer action, be consistent about your use of pointers and deallocation.