# The difference between RAII and smart pointers in C++

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, raii

The difference between those two is not clear for me, yet. What I have read about them have been very massive and complex (as the C++ is). For example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395123/raii-and-smart-pointers-in-c) which belongs to years ago and from WikiPedia as well. Probably the issue is complex in itself.

What I think about them is that, RAII is a mechanism that we use it for smart pointers, but I'm not sure about this. I need a simple and straightforward answer.

Would you please explain it in a simple language with a small sample code?
Please bear in mind that I'm at a low level in C++.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[**RAII**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) is the idea of using C++'s automatic call of a destructor, to release resources acquired in a constructor.

The acronym indicates that only vaguely, *Resource Acquisition Is Initialization*.

A [**smart pointer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one) is a class that overloads at least `operator->` and the dereference `operator*` to enable use with pointer notation. Typically a smart pointer will use RAII techniques to automatically deallocate memory. But it can do other things. It is however implicit that a smart pointer deals somehow with ”ownership” of a contained raw pointer. For example, a simple iterator class overloads `operator->` and `operator*` but is not regarded as a smart pointer.

Answer (score 8):

They're complimentary concepts. RAII means that objects take care of their own resources automatically. Smart pointers are a way of accomplishing RAII for allocated memory.

Comment: Thanks Mark. So what I'd think of them was correct! :)

Answer (score 2):

[RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) is a technique:

> Resource Acquisition Is Initialization or RAII, is a C++ programming technique[1][2] which binds the life cycle of a resource (**allocated memory, thread of execution, open socket, open file, locked mutex, database connection—anything that exists in limited supply**) to the lifetime of an object with automatic storage duration.

RAII's concept includes all the limited resources, while [Smart points](http://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) are expected to manage dynamically-allocated memory or any resource represented by a plain pointer, follow RAII.