# Wrapper to build std::unique_ptr with plain function deleters

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14

I was trying to implement an `std::unique_ptr` factory that I could use like this:

```
auto fd = my_make_unique<fclose>(fopen("filename", "r"));
```

I.e., pass the deleter function as a template argument.

My best attempt in C++11 was:

```
template<typename D, D deleter, typename P>
struct Deleter {
    void operator()(P* ptr) {
        deleter(ptr);
    }
};

template<typename D, D deleter, typename P>
std::unique_ptr<P, Deleter<D, deleter, P>> my_make_unique(P* ptr)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<P, Deleter<D, deleter, P>>(ptr);
}
```

In C++14 it is much cleaner:

```
template<typename D, D deleter, typename P>
auto my_make_unique(P* ptr)
{
    struct Deleter {
        void operator()(P* ptr) {
            deleter(ptr);
        }
    };
    return std::unique_ptr<P, Deleter>(ptr);
}
```

But both solutuions would require me to pass the type of `&fclose` before `fclose` itself as template argument:

```
auto fd = my_make_unique<decltype(&fclose), fclose>(fopen("filename", "r"));
```

Is it possible to get rid of `decltype(&fclose)` template argument in C++11? What about in C++14?

EDIT: Why this question is not a duplicate of [RAII and smart pointers in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395123/raii-and-smart-pointers-in-c): referenced question is about general RAII techniques in C++, and one of the answers estates that `std::unique_ptr` can be used for this purpose. I am already familiar with RAII pattern and how `std::unique_ptr` is a solution, but I am concerned with present question on how to build an easier to use abstraction to this frequent case I encounter when interacting with C libraries.

Comment: `FILE*` was just an example everyone is acquainted to. This is most useful to interact with C libraries full of `create_<type>()` and `destroy_<type>()` functions. Anyway, `*` and `->` are available for plain `FILE *` pointers, too, and it is no worse inside `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: I disagree with this duplication mark, my question is much more specific.

Comment: Most voted answer in this other questions shows usage `RAIIFunc<int (int), ::close> f = ::open("...");`, which, as my solution, also requires the type of the destructor function as the first template argument. My question is specifically how to remove that template argument (if possible).

Comment: Taking the address of a standard library function is undefined. thus passing fclose as a template argument is undefined behavior (even so it works), because a standard library implementation is free to add additional overlaods or more parameters with default arguments, only the calls are specified to work (with some exceptions) see https://wg21.link/p0551 R>=3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to get rid of `decltype(&fclose)` template argument in C++11? What about in C++14?

No, not until C++17 can you get rid of the type of that parameter. Template non-type parameters *need* a type, which you can't deduce - because it has to be a template non-type parameter. That's one problem.

*Additionally*, you have the problem that taking the address of functions in the standard library is unspecified. The standard library is always allowed to provide additional overloads, for instance, so `&fclose` may be invalid. The only truly portable way of doing this is to provide a lambda or write your own wrapper function:

```
auto my_fclose_lam = [](std::FILE* f) { std::fclose(f); }
void my_fclose_fun(std::FILE* f) { std::fclose(f); }
```

And with either of those, with C++14 at best you can introduce a macro like:

```
#define DECL(v) decltype(v), v
auto fd = my_make_unique<DECL(my_fclose_lam)>(fopen("filename", "r"));
```

C++17 allows you to at least lift your custom function into a template parameter (though not yet a lambda) via `template auto`:

```
template <auto deleter, typename P>
auto my_make_unique(P* ptr)
{
    struct Deleter {
        void operator()(P* ptr) {
            deleter(ptr);
        }
    };
    return std::unique_ptr<P, Deleter>(ptr);
}

my_make_unique<my_fclose_fun>(fopen(...));
```

C++20 will finally allow you to stick a lambda into there:

```
my_make_unique<[](std::FILE* f){ std::fclose(f); }>(fopen(...));
```

---

Old incorrect answer:

<s>So the best you can do is introduce a macro like:</s>

```
#define DECL(v) decltype(v), v
auto fd = my_make_unique<DECL(&fclose)>(fopen("filename", "r"));
```

Whether or not you think that's a good idea is probably up to your coworkers.

---

In C++17, with `template auto`, you could just be able to write `my_make_unique<fclose>`, which is great:

```
template <auto deleter, typename P>
auto my_make_unique(P* ptr)
{
    struct Deleter {
        void operator()(P* ptr) {
            deleter(ptr);
        }
    };
    return std::unique_ptr<P, Deleter>(ptr);
}
```

Comment: see my comment to the question, taking the address of fclose is non-portable and not sanctioned by the C++ standard (will be more explicit verboten in C++2a)

Answer (score 4):

Pragmatic approach: Make the deleter a runtime parameter.

```
template<typename P, typename D>
auto my_make_unique(P* ptr, D deleter)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<P, D>(ptr, deleter);
}

int main()
{
    auto fd = my_make_unique(fopen("filename", "r"), fclose);     
}
```

Comment: This is what I am currently doing. The drawback, besides the possibly larger structure, is that the return type (that I typedef to something) is not default constructible.

Comment: see above. &fclose is verboten.

Comment: @PeterSom What do you want to tell me?

Comment: It is unspecified to take the address of a standard library function. That includes the functions inherited from the C library, such as fclose. To make this answer correct, fclose must not be given directly as an argument. One workaround would be a lambda calling fclose and passing that.

Comment: @PeterSom I see. I will update this answer when I find some time.

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround is use exactly signature of function:

```
template<typename T, int (*P)(T*)> //for `fclose`
auto my_make_unique(T*) { ... }

template<typename T, void (*P)(T*)> //for other function signatures
auto my_make_unique(T*) { ... }

//etc.

auto uniq = my_make_unique<File, fclose>(fopen("filename", "r"));
```

This is not universal solution but in 95% cases will work.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to create a `std::unique_ptr` for a `FILE*` pointer is:

```
auto fd = std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(fclose)>(fopen(...), fclose);
```

You could wrap that in a macro:

```
#define my_make_unique(ptr, deleter) \
    std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<decltype<ptr>>::type, d>(ptr, deleter)
```

And then use it like this:

```
auto fd = my_make_unique(fopen(...), fclose);
```