# Is smart pointer a good practice of RAII?

Tags: c++, raii

To start with, here is a discussion of [RAII&Smart Pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395123/raii-and-smart-pointers-in-c).
I've always thought that Smart Pointer like `shared_ptr` is a good practice of RAII because it gets the heap memory resource at constructor like

```
shared_ptr<A> pA(new pA());
```

and could free the memory at right time through reference counting and its destructor.
However, this morning my collegue told me that:

> "**smart pointer** is not what i thought to be **RAII**. The only thing that **can strictly be called as RAII** in the STL is `std::lock_guard`, the others are nothing more than **RRID**.  "

So did i get something wrong? Or what my collegue said actually made non-sense?

Comment: RRID is what exactly?

Comment: @john _Resource Release Is Destruction_

Comment: shared_ptr is definitely RAII, but of course, a shared pointer represents shared ownership. RRID is just a better name for the standard term RAII.

Comment: Using the term "STL" like that suggests that your colleague may not be very precise in his definitions.

Comment: @ErikAlapää Is that true?I've heard that **RAII is a superset of RRID**.I've tried to find something of **RRID** in stackoverflow,but there are few discussions  about that.

Comment: Perhaps all your colleague really wanted to say is that "RAII" is a bad name for the idiom because it puts the emphasis on construction when the defining part is definitely destruction. But that's old news; everyone knows what "RAII" really means, and no one takes it that literally.

Comment: @bigxiao Yes, true. I am not sure, but I even think Stroustrup himself (or maybe it was ISO chair Herb Sutter...) said that RRID would have been a better name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### From cppreference:

> *Resource Acquisition Is Initialization or RAII, is a C++ programming technique which binds the life cycle of a resource that must be acquired before use (allocated heap memory, thread of execution, open socket, open file, locked mutex, disk space, database connection—anything that exists in limited supply) to the lifetime of an object.*

`std::shared_ptr` is definitely RAII as it aquires a resource and binds its lifetime to its own, thus taking over the responsibility of releasing/destructing the resource. This is the core principle of RAII.

The term *RRID* (Resource Release Is Destruction) is rarely seen and its meaning seems to be somewhat ambiguous. Mostly it is used with the same meaning as RAII.

IMHO many discussions revolving around variants of RAII deem from interpreting the meaning of the term too exactly. RAII is meant to represent a concept of object life-time management.